# How do I log what user deleted a record in MS Access?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access, ms-access-2003

It's a MS Access app with linked tables to SQL Server. I need to log this on the SQL Server as I cannot modify the MS Access app.

The app connects to the SQL Server through a default SQL username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a trigger for this, and a table to store the results. Very quick prototype:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trigger_name
ON dbo.table_name
FOR DELETE
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.LogTable(RowID, UserName)
        SELECT PK_Column, SUSER_SNAME()
        FROM deleted;
GO
```

Note that unless each Access user authenticates to SQL Server as themselves, you may need to use host name or some other property to identify them (if they all connect as the same SQL user, there is little SQL Server can do to determine who they really are).

Comment: For some reason, when I use HOSTNAME(), it returns the same HOSTNAME() for multiple users for the off-site users. I think it's a network issue. SUSERNAME() returns the BOGUS. I cannot modify the Access app so I cannot have them each authenticate.

Comment: Yeah SQL Server can't get to the remote machine to see the host name, it can only see whatever host name passed that request to SQL Server. And you're going to have a hard time getting the Windows user name if they are using SQL authentication (I assume that is what `BOGUS` is). I am not sure how Profiler is showing the actual user name - are you sure it's accurate for all users? Where is Profiler running from, the same machine where the Access app is running?

Comment: Profiler is running from my machine where as the SQL Server is running on a server and the Access app is running from different network shares.

Comment: Interesting. The SUSER_SNAME() works for some users and not for others. For some it shows dom\user other is shows BOGUS.

Comment: Are you sure they're all using SQL authentication? You should be able to check `sys.dm_exec_connections.auth_scheme`...